# Getting nested Document from mongo db using java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, nested, mongo-java

I need to create an Object graph for the documents in a collection.
I am able to get all the key-value pairs. Here is the code which does that:

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GetKeyValuePair {
public static void print(DBObject doc) {
    Set<String> allKeys = doc.keySet();
    Iterator<String> it = allKeys.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String temp = it.next();
        System.out.print(temp + "-");
        if (doc.get(temp) instanceof BasicDBObject) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            print((DBObject) doc.get(temp));
        } else {
            System.out.println(doc.get(temp));
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Mongo m = new Mongo();
        DB db = m.getDB("test");
        Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("first");

        DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
        DBCursor cur = coll.find();
        Set<String> allKeys;
        Iterator<String> it;
        while (cur.hasNext()) {
            doc = cur.next();
            allKeys = doc.keySet();
            it = allKeys.iterator();
            print(doc);
            System.out.println("-------");
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } catch (MongoException.DuplicateKey e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Caught" + e);
    }
   }}
```

Is there any other way I can do this, I mean a rather simple way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to explain better what the problem is and what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you looking for your posted code to be re-factored? Or are you questioning the approach entirely?

Comment: @Tim I was asking for an entire new approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case allows it and existing Java ORM mappers such as Morphia don't work for you you can use ReflectionDBObject. If not you're stuck with your approach, there are no shortcuts.